# "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in ..." when I use the return statement

Tags: php, parse-error, return

This is part of a bigger code, I keep getting the parse error ::: if I create the if function outside of the $return & reference it with a session it works but this is not "good" coding :::how can I resolve this nagging issue or better construct my return value? ::: Any help greatly appreciated :::

```
$return = '';
    $return .='<div id="viewport">'. "\n";
    $return .= $ic . "\n";
    $return .='<div id="' . $wallID . '"></div>'. "\n"; 
    $return .='</div>'. "\n";                                  
    $return .= if( isset($coda) )'<div id="coda' . $wallID . '"></div>';. "\n";
    $return .='</div>'. "\n";                                   
    $return .='<div class="clearfix"></div>'. "\n";

 return $return;
```

Comment: Which line is the error in? Please always specify the line of the error message

Comment: Ah, I see now. You can't use `if`  like that - put it before the `$return.=` assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ternary operator instead of the misused if block:

```
$return .= isset($coda) ? "<div id='coda{$wallID}'></div>\n" : '';
```

or a more readable if block as @Mat sugested

Answer (score 3):

Just use a proper `if`:

```
...
if( isset($coda) ) {
  $return .= '<div id="coda' . $wallID . '"></div>'. "\n";
}
$return .= ...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is probably problematic

```
$return .= if( isset($coda) )'<div id="coda' . $wallID . '"></div>';. "\n";
```

it should be

```
$return .= ((isset($coda)) ? '<div id="coda' . $wallID . '"></div>' : '')."\n";
```

To make it all more clean, I'd suggest you to use [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: THX for the heads up on HEREDOC ::: Read some documentation & implemented it in my code ... looks much cleaner